# Is it possible to put the bootstrap tab-content outside the tab panel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want the make bootstrap tabs work even outside the tab panel. I have seen the tabs work outside the tab-panel just like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/s6bP9/. But i want it in different way.

I have 2 paragraphs outside the bootstrap tab-panel and bootstrap tabs code below. i want class **first para** to be displayed along with bootstrap tab-content when i click the **#tab1** nav-tabs links and **second para** to be displayed on click of **#tab2** link.

```
<body>
<p>This content is linked to tab1</p>
<p>This content is linked to tab2</p>

<div role="tabpanel" class="row">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs benefits-tab fa-ul" role="tablist">
                           <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">

                                <h1>TAB1</h1>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">

                                <h1>TAB2</h1>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>

                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the classes `firstPara` and `secondPara` to your two paragraphs and then use the following code.

```
$('.secondPara').hide();

$('a[data-toggle="tab"][href="#tab1"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.firstPara').show();
    $('.secondPara').hide();
})

$('a[data-toggle="tab"][href="#tab2"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.firstPara').hide();
    $('.secondPara').show();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6bP9/42/

Comment: Thank you so much DGS .. it worked for me. Hats off to you.  I am able to access the specific tab from the reference in another page using the javascript in this link http://www.bootply.com/rg7f7CLlFR . But when i open the tab2 directly from the link in the another page i get the `firstPara` element's content. Can i get the exact content(i.e, `secondPara`'s element on click of that link. I know this is hapenning because of `$('.secondPara').hide();` . Cant we get the exact content???

Comment: Yeah the `$('.secondPara').hide()` call is just there to default the `firstPara` to be the first paragraph shown.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/punkhaa/k6vbgf3d/1/   hope this works for you

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click',function(){
        console.log("aaa",$(".para_"+$(this).attr('aria-controls')));
        $($(this).attr('href')).append($(".para_"+$(this).attr('aria-controls')).html());
    })
})`